# add value in a column whenever other column has specifc value python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "price":[44,21,33,44,55,66,454, 22],
   "store":["A", "A", "B", "A","A", "A", "A", "A"]
})
```

which gives:

```
    price   store
0   44      A
1   21      A
2   33      B
3   44       A
4   55      A
5   66      A
6   454     A
7   22      A
```

Whenever store = "A" I want to add up the price until another store= "B" is reached. Then again whenever I get store="A" I sum prices and so on...

So in this case I would have 2 cycles of store = "A" and I would get

cycle 1: 44 + 21

cycle 2: 44 + 55 + 66 + 454 + 22.

It would be better to get index of cycle 1 ([0,1] and cycle 2[3,4,5,6,7] but only getting the sum will suffice.

What I've tried:

```
start_value = "A"

d = {}
lst = []
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["store"] != start_value:
        d[ind] = lst   
        print(d)
        lst = []
    else:
        lst.append(row["price"])
d["last"] = lst
```

This outputs what I've desired `{"2":[44, 21], "last":[44, 33, 66, 454, 22]}`. But any alternative ways or faults in my method?

Comment: you could share what you have tried to solve the problem

Comment: Why not just `df[df['store']=='A']['price'].sum()`?

Comment: @rahlf23 I need different sum for each cycle of store A. Your method simply totals all store A prices.

Comment: Why are you using `.iterrows()`? Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, using `pandas.Groupby` with `cumsum`:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby(df['store'].ne(df['store'].shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   price store  sum
0     44     A   44
1     21     A   65
2     33     B   33
3     44     A   44
4     55     A   99
5     66     A  165
6    454     A  619
7     22     A  641
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print({k:v for k, v in df.groupby(df['store'].ne(df['store'].shift()).cumsum())['price'].agg(list).to_dict().items() if len(v) > 1})
```

Output:

```
{1: [44, 21], 3: [44, 33, 66, 454, 22]}
```